# Ubuntu 20.04 default backup program not backing up .dbus file

Tags: 12.04, backup, deja-dup, timeshift

Deja-dup dose not backup .dbus Ubuntu 20.04.
If I use timeshift -/home/username and Deja-dup can I restore with fresh install off Ubuntu 20.04, restore with timeshift with snapshot on USB stick, and restore /home/username with Deja-dup. Will this .dbus error when backing up with Deja-dup be a problem.

There was some other answer about .dbus and backup but I did not understand it.
I know about clonzilla, but I don't want to use that I like timeshift!

Comment: Dose backing up .dbux even matter or will,it be created in fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. Then restoring timeshift snapshot and restoring backup without .dbus if I'm not mistaken should work correct. Can someone say yes or no? Summary i don't think .dbus needs to be ba kted up.

Comment: It's answered in the duplicate link: ~/.dbus does not need to be backed up.